# UNIX grep command

Tags: unix, command, grep

so this question is about UNIX grep command. I'm trying to execute this command : grep '[^echo]' test (test is the file name). Unfortunatly, all its doing is just printing the content of the file. Any idea of whats its supposed to do or why is it not doing anything?

text :

```
abc hello what is up
123 I am testing this
echo utility 123124135
xyz
```

Output is the same exact text.

Answer (score 7):

The pattern `[^echo]` matches any character except `e`, `c`, `h`, and `o`.  The input line "echo utility 123124135" for example contains all of these characters, but it *also* contains characters that are *not* `e`, `c`, `h`, nor `o`.  So it **does** match the pattern.  So do all of the other lines, because they all contain characters other than these.

If you add an input line "echohce" to your data file, you should note that it is omitted when you run grep with your pattern, because it does *not* contain any other characters.

If you want grep to output all of the lines that don't contain the text "echo" then try `grep -v echo test`.  The `-v` switch tells grep to invert the sense of the match: output lines that *don't* match the pattern.  And the pattern "echo" will match any line that contains the text "echo".

If you are trying to output all of the lines that *start* with "echo" then try `grep ^echo test`.

Comment: why can't you do grep "[^echo].*" test?

Comment: You could certainly do that.  But that would have no semantic difference from `[^echo]`.  In this context they would both match the same set of lines for *any* random input.  This is because `.*` can (and will) match nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way:

```
cat text | grep echo
```

That will print the line with the word "echo" on the screen

Comment: Look out for that [UUOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat)!

Comment: Your example is equivalent to `grep echo text`. The important difference which you did not point out is that you changed the pattern from `[^echo]` to `echo` which are very different regular expressions.

Comment: @cdhowie Hehe I wasn't aware of such a thing as UUOC. I just realized that I can simply do grep echo text ;)

Comment: @R Samuel Klatchko thanks for clarifying that for me and Nidale.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to match `echo` at the beginning of a line, try

```
grep "^echo" test
```

However, if you are trying to match all lines that do not contain `echo` then try

```
grep -v "echo" test
```

EDIT: oops, I've just realised that this is a cut-down version of @cdhowie's answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the lines that do not contain the word 'echo', try

```
grep -v "echo" test
```